How to make DB2 SSL Connection using Vertx?
We have been trying to connect with Mainframe DB2 using SSL connectivity, but didn't get any success yet. Mainframe DB2 connectivity using SSL is working fine in case of normal com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource driver. But our requirement is to use reactive DB2 driver and that's why we choose Vertx. We are using the same certificate which we have used for the normal jcc driver connectivity.
Below is the serverhello log from my local,
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.313 EDT|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 122 javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.315 EDT|ServerHello.java:867|Consuming ServerHello handshake message ( "ServerHello": { "server version"      : "TLSv1.2", "random"              : "C3 3D 72 E9 13 AC C5 C5 77 A4 81 95 F7 71 40 46 8E 0B 15 19 73 92 F3 90 0B 4C 75 E7 48 43 BD 36", "session id"          : "7A 4A 7E CC 2D 6D 02 5A 4F 80 B9 DA 5D 3B 68 45 F1 B6 7B 3F 84 77 BF E2 D8 27 94 06 4D 30 D2 A9", "cipher suite"        : "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302)", "compression methods" : "00", "extensions"          : [ "supported_versions (43)": { "selected version": [TLSv1.3] }, "key_share (51)": { "server_share": { "named group": x25519 "key_exchange": { 0000: 22 AF 76 CD AB C6 8B A8   CE 70 DD 12 B4 17 98 A4  ".v......p...... 0010: 04 63 2B F0 64 39 25 B4   F9 B8 E0 8C 82 B3 B2 27  .c+.d9%........' } }, } ] } )

Below is the remaining log from local,
    javax.net.ssl|ALL|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.418 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:760|Closing outbound of SSLEngine javax.net.ssl|WARNING|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.419 EDT|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.419 EDT|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:529|WRITE: TLSv1.3 alert, length = 2 javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.420 EDT|SSLCipher.java:2062|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION ( 0000: 01 00 15 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................ 0010: 00 00 00                                           ... ) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0|2024-04-10 14:59:25.420 EDT|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:550|Raw write ( 0000: 17 03 03 00 23 BE 26 39   EE E9 49 17 AA DC 68 E6  ....#.&9..I...h. 0010: E3 12 D7 CD 18 9F D2 05   34 3A 8B D1 31 16 4E 59  ........4:..1.NY 0020: 48 26 C6 EF D1 C6 AA 1E                            H&...... ) Failure: The connection was closed by the database server., SQLCODE=-4499  SQLSTATE=08004.C.3

On DB2 side logs showing below error for ServerHello,
    Supported Version length: 3 [Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Vector length 3 is too large, truncating it to 1]] [Vector length 3 is too large, truncating it to 1] [Severity level: Error] [Group: Malformed]

Our Mainframe DB2 support guys are saying, there may be configuration issue.
Below is my java code,
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {connectSsl(Vertx.vertx()); }

    public static void connectSsl(Vertx vertx) {

    //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");
    DB2ConnectOptions options = (DB2ConnectOptions) new DB2ConnectOptions()
        .setPort(XXXXXX)
        .setHost("XXXXXX")
        .setDatabase("XXXXXX")
        .setSsl(true)                
        .addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.2")
        .setTrustAll(true)
        .setTrustStoreOptions(new JksOptions()
                .setPath("<Path to .jks file>")
                .setPassword("XXXXXX"));

    Set<String> ciphers = options.getEnabledCipherSuites(); // We are getting cipher size =     0, So, it will not print any CipherSuites
    Iterator<String> ciphersIterator = ciphers.iterator();
    while(ciphersIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("CipherSuites - "+ciphersIterator.next());
}

    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);


    SqlClient sc =  DB2Builder.client().with(poolOptions).connectingTo(options).using(vertx).build();

    sc.query("SELECT XXX, XXX FROM XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX WHERE XXXX='XXXX'")
        .execute()
        .onComplete(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                RowSet<Row> result = ar.result();
                System.out.println("Got " + result.size() + " rows ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
            }
            // Now close the pool
            sc.close();
        });

}

Am I missing anything here? What configuration I am missing here?
Please suggest the solution as it's critical for the project development.
We manually added the cipherSuite but that is also didn't workout.
    Set<String> cipherSuites=new HashSet<>();
    cipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");
    cipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");
    cipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
    cipherSuites.add("TLS_CDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
    SSLEngineOptions sslEngineOptions=new JdkSSLEngineOptions();
    sslEngineOptions.sslContextFactory().enabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    DB2ConnectOptions options = (DB2ConnectOptions) new     DB2ConnectOptions().setPort().setHost("") .setDatabase("****").setSsl(true).setSslEngineOptions(sslEngineOptions)


Does the vertx driver support connecting with a certificate directly, i.e. instead of using a java keystore? Just a suggestion to eliminate that indirection to help PD/PSI.  If the vertx driver supports debugging (i.e. to show exactly what packets are sent to Db2, and what packets are returned) , if so you should investigate to dig under the covers.  As IBM might have no interest here (if no IBM supplied driver is involved), you should engage with the supplier of vertx for debugging, as Stackoverflow might not be the correct channel.

Also, you could check if the vertx driver works with ssl with Db2-LUW (because that is more widely available, docker versions exist etc) and if the same symptom occurrs with Db2-LUW then debugging is a lot easier than on mainframe Db2-for-Z/OS. (In case the same symptom happens with LUW).
